# BigQuery - Query for each and set elements in column

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I would like to loop over several elements for a query.

Here is the query :

```
SELECT
  timestamp_trunc(timestamp, DAY) as Day,
  count(1) as Number
FROM `table`
WHERE user_id="12345" AND timestamp >= '2021-07-05 00:00:00 UTC' AND timestamp <= '2021-07-08 23:59:59 UTC'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY Day
```

So I have for the user "12345" a row counter per each day between two dates, this is perfect.

But I would like to do this query for each user_id of my table,
and if possible I would like each day on column, so each row is a user and the number available for each column (which is a day).

Result wanted :

```
User   | 2021-07-05 | 2021-07-06 | 2021-07-07
---------------------------------------------
user_1 | 345        | 16         | 41
user_2 | 555        | 53         | 26
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below approach

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    user_id,
    DATE(timestamp) as Day,
    COUNT(1) as Number
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE timestamp >= '2021-07-05 00:00:00 UTC' AND timestamp <= '2021-07-08 23:59:59 UTC'
  GROUP BY 1, 2
)
PIVOT (SUM(Number) FOR Day IN ('2021-07-05','2021-07-06','2021-07-07'))
```

Or even simpler (w/o GROUP BY as in your original query)

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT
    user_id,
    DATE(timestamp) as Day,
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
  WHERE timestamp >= '2021-07-05 00:00:00 UTC' AND timestamp <= '2021-07-08 23:59:59 UTC'
)
PIVOT (COUNT(*) FOR Day IN ('2021-07-05','2021-07-06','2021-07-07'))
```

Comment: Amazing !! Thank you :)